# Create classes in a loop where the class name comes from a list

Tags: python

I am basically trying to extract song names from a playlist, and then I want to create a class for each song in the playlist that includes all the relevant data for that song (song title, artist, location of each song etc.)

I have a list where each item in the list is a song name. I am trying to create a loop that creates a new class named after each item in the list.

This is what I have so far:

```
class MyClass():
    var = "hi"

songNames = ['song1', 'song2', 'song3']

for name in songNames:
    name = MyClass()
```

This is not working and I think it's because Python is having trouble/can't assign a name to a class like that. I am a beginner with Python and after extensive searching I could not come up with a solution. What is the correct way to do this?

---

So I've been working on the code and have made some progress:

```
class SongData(object):
    def __init__(self, title="", artist="", directory=""):
        self.title, self.artist, self.directory = title, artist, directory
    def __str__(self):
        desc_str = "Title: %s \nArtist: %s \nDirectory: %s \n" %(self.title,
                                            self.artist, self.directory)
        print desc_str

songNames = ['song1', 'song2', 'song3']
artistNames = ['artist1', 'artist2', 'artist3']
dirNames = ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3']

songs = {name: SongData(title=name) for name in songNames}
artists = {band: SongData(artist=band) for band in artistNames}
directorys = {direc: SongData(directory=direc) for direc in dirNames}
```

I would like to be able to print out the `desc_str` for each song so it appears like this:

```
Title: song1 
Artist: artist1 
Directory: dir1
```

But so far I have only managed to call one data category at once, so it prints `Title: song1` but leaves the `Artist:` and `Directory:` sections blank.

How can I get it to print them out all at once?

Comment: Why not just use a list or a dictionary to hold the class instances?

Comment: What does "not working" do? Python certainly _can_ assign a class instance to a name like that. But it isn't going to do you any good; you're just assigning a value to a variable that you immediately replace with a different value.

Comment: As a side note, that `var = "hi"` is almost certainly a mistake. That creates a class attribute, shared by all instances, instead of an instance attribute, which is different for each instance. If you don't understand the difference, you do not want class attributes.

Comment: One last thing: You should never write `class MyClass():`. If this is Python 2, create a new-style class with `class MyClass(object):`. If this is Python 3, you don't need that—but in that case, just write `class MyClass:` with no parens at all.

Comment: I don't know if this is the correct usage, but I had intended by class to look something like the following, because every song was going to have all the same variables: `class songData: title = "" artist = "" directory = "" tempStr = "" def description(self): desc_str = "%s is by %s, located at %s" %(self.title, self.artist,self.directory) return desc_str`

Comment: @NickCamps: It's very hard to read code in a comment on SO; it's better to either edit your question, ask a new question, or paste somewhere like http://pastebin.com and post a link.

Comment: @NickCamps: Anyway, what you're showing has the same issue: you're creating class variables rather than instance variables, which you don't want to do. Let me edit my answer to show the right way to do it.

Comment: @NickCamps You should read [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Comment: @poorsod: I don't think he actually wants to create dynamically-named variables here. But if he _does_—or if some future reader does—that's a great explanation for why he shouldn't.

Comment: If you have a separate followup question, it's generally better to create a new question, and link the two together. A new question will get the attention of all the people who could possibly help; a followup on the same question only gets the attention of the handful who happen to stumble upon an already-answered question and see the followup.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't want to create a class for each song; you want to create an *instance* of a class for each song. For example:

```
class Song(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

songNames = ['song1', 'song2', 'song3']

songs = []
for name in songNames:
    songs.append(Song(name))
```

Notice that I'm storing the `Song` objects in a list. You need to store them *somewhere*, or you can't access them again later, right?

If you want to be able to access them by name later, instead of just looping over all of them:

```
songs = {}
for name in songNames:
    songs[name] = Song(name)
```

And you can convert either of those into a one-liner using a comprehension:

```
songs = [Song(name) for name in songNames]
songs = {name: Song(name) for name in songNames}
```

---

From a comment:

> I had intended by class to look something like the following, because every song was going to have all the same variables:

```
class songData: 
    title = "" 
    artist = "" 
    directory = "" 
    tempStr = ""
    def description(self): 
        desc_str = "%s is by %s, located at %s" %(self.title, self.artist,self.directory)
        return desc_str
```

This is wrong for the same reasons I already explained: You're creating class attributes, not instance attributes. This means every instance will share a single title, etc., which is not what you want. Also, it means `self.title` is misleading (although it will work).

Meanwhile, if this is Python 2, you're again creating a classic class. Also, you probably want a `__str__` method rather than a special `description` method, because then you can just `print(song)` instead of having to `print(song.description())`. Finally, it's a bit confusing to use the same naming convention for variables and classes.

What you probably want is:

```
class SongData:
    def __init__(self, title="", artist="", directory=""):
        self.title, self.artist, self.directory = title, artist, directory
    def __str__(self): 
        desc_str = "%s is by %s, located at %s" % (self.title, self.artist,self.directory)
        return desc_str
```

Now, you can use this basically the same way as the `Song` class above:

```
songNames = ['song1', 'song2', 'song3']
songs = {name: SongData(title=name) for name in songNames}
```

Now you can do things like this:

```
name = input('What song do you want info on?') # raw_input, if Python 2
print(songs[name])
```

(Of course this isn't very useful unless you also have code that sets the artist and directory somewhere, because it'll just print `Song Windowlicker is by , located at`. But I don't know where you intend to get those from.)

---

Your new code has two problems. First:

```
def __str__(self):
    desc_str = "Title: %s \nArtist: %s \nDirectory: %s \n" %(self.title,
                                        self.artist, self.directory)
    print desc_str
```

You need to `return desc_str` here, not `print` it.

---

Second:

```
songNames = ['song1', 'song2', 'song3']
artistNames = ['artist1', 'artist2', 'artist3']
dirNames = ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3']

songs = {name: SongData(title=name) for name in songNames}
artists = {band: SongData(artist=band) for band in artistNames}
directorys = {direc: SongData(directory=direc) for direc in dirNames}
```

Here you're creating three separate collections of `SongData` objects, each of which only has one attribute filled.

The key here is [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip). It's one of the most useful functions in Python once you get what it does, but until you know about it you'd never think to look for it. It's easier to describe if I show what it does:

```
>>> zip(songNames, artistNames, dirNames)
[('song1', 'artist1', 'dir1'),
 ('song2', 'artist2', 'dir2'),
 ('song3', 'artist3', 'dir3')]
```

So, that gives you a list of tuples, where each tuple has a song name, an artist, and a dir. The first tuple is the first of each, the second is the second of each, etc.

Now you can build a `SongData` out of each tuple pretty easily:

```
songs = {}
for title, artist, directory in zip(songNames, artistNames, dirNames):
     songs[title] = SongData(title, artist, directory)
```

As a dict comprehension, it gets a little verbose:

```
songs = {title: SongData(title, artist, directory)
         for title, artist, directory in zip(songNames, artistNames, dirNames)}
```

But you can simplify it with another trick: [unpacking arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
songs = {t[0]: SongData(*t) for songtuple in zip(songNames, artistNames, dirNames)}
```

Of course you *could* do this without `zip`, but it would look like a mess:

```
songs = {SongData(songNames[i], artistNames[i], dirNames[i])
         for i in range(len(songNames))}
```

… and if you have a small bug with mismatched lists, it will be hard to understand and debug this way. Generally, whenever you write `for i in range(len(foo))` in Python, there's probably a simple way.

---

However you build it, you can use it just as you'd expect:

```
>>> print songs['song1']
Title: song1 
Artist: artist1 
Directory: directory1
```

---

While we're at it, you probably don't want a space at the end of each line of output. It's not visible to humans, but it could confuse code you later write to parse the output, and it wastes space, and there's no real benefit. Just put each `\n` right after the `%s`.

Comment: I've edited a follow-up question into my original question, I would really appreciate your help again if you don't mind.

Comment: @NickCamps: I've answered it here, but for future reference, that's not a good way to do it; just create a new question. You'll get more answers and comments, and more rep points to boot.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that it seems like you want to create an instance rather than a class for each song. But if you do want to create a class for each song, use the `type(className, parentTuple, attributeDict)` function. It returns a new class with the given name.

E.g.

```
songClasses = []
for name in songNames:
    songClasses.append(type(name, (), {}))
```